# Is there a way to save/write a text file in the renderer process without opening the dialog box in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, electron

Hey i am working in this project(app) based on VueJs + electron and trying to save a text file to the user pc but  i don't want any prompt or dialog  box to pop up .Is there a way to achieve this ?Note that i know how to do it using require('fs') but **fs** does not work inside renderer process.So i am trying to use a different method .Currently i am using **require('file-saver')** but the problem is it is also opening a dialog box asking where to save the file.I want that the file be saved wherever(except the root directory obviously)i want it to by specifying the path.PS:I know that there are security reasons so browser cant directly save the file.But the thing is i have 100s of files that i want to save and i don't want the user to click **ok** for each file.The code that i am using is as below:

```
methods:
{

 uploadClicked:function(){
      
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

 FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to send the string to the main process and use `fs` from their?

In your renderer process

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
//#2
//Pass argument 
ipcRenderer.send('save-file', options);
```

In your main process

```
const { ipcMain  } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs') 

ipcMain.on('save-file', (ev, options )=>{
    //try save with fs
    fs...
  // send notifications after save
  ev.reply()
})
```